# shell temp variable identification

Tags: shell, scripting

```
echo "\n\n enter judge name:\c"
    read jnm
    cnt=`grep -c "^$jnm" judge.txt`
    if [ $cnt -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "record not found"
    else
        echo "1. Update"
        echo "2. Delete"
        echo "3. Cancel"
        echo "enter your choice:"
        read ch
        if [ -e temp ]
        then
            rm temp # what does this temp store 
        fi
        if [ $ch -eq 3 ]
        then
            echo "record not deleted"
        elif [ $ch -eq 1 -o $ch -eq 2 ]
        then
        for i in `cat judge.txt`
        do
            jname=`echo $i | cut -d ':' -f1`
            if [ "$jname" = "$jnm" ]
            then
            if [ $ch -eq 1 ]
            then
                addrecord 1
                echo "$jnm:$cnm:$city:$cjudged:$tcases" >> temp
            fi
            else
                echo $i >> temp
            fi
        done
        rm judge.txt
        mv temp judge.txt
        if [ $ch -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "record is updated"
        else
            echo "record is deleted"
        fi 
        else
        echo "invalid choice"
        fi
    fi
```

I have mentioned the problem detail in comment.
What exactly is temp storing in this first if condition of update.
How does -e works on single operand and what is this temp.
I tried searching for it but i didn't found anything.
This code is Just a certain portion of code not entire code.
Code is working perfectly. Is there any altrenative or solution if i want to use two operands with -e what would be they?.

Answer (score 1):

"temp" is a literal filename; `[ -e temp ]` checks to see if the file exists. The script removes it if so, presumably because the later `echo`s all *append* to the file (`>> temp`) and so would not remove whatever was already in the file when the script started.

There is no variable involved; the name of the file is literally "temp".

Comment: but the script works even after commenting entire first if condition of if [ -e temp ]  why is that so.how does it identify the file?

Comment: it creates the file regardless (and then renames it to `judge.txt` at the end).  The test just gets rid of any preexisting version of the file so old data doesn't show up in the final result.

Comment: so why is that rm temp in if block?.

Comment: To avoid unnecessarily running `rm`, I suppose.  But an `rm -f` would have done the trick just as well.

Comment: so does it mean when i run my program again if the temp file already exists then this if condition should remove that file?

Comment: @user5681186 - It does, of course; you can read the statements nearly literally: _If exists temp, then remove temp._